# JavaScript skips function that adds values to arrays for Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, html5-canvas, setinterval

I'm creating an animated pie chart with .arc() and setInterval().  Getting the piechart to animate has not been a problem.  The issue I've had that's held me back is that when I animate each slice of the pie, when the slice finishes animating, it's start and end values are supposed to be entered into an array.  However for whatever reason the code only starts working (i.e. saving the values to the arrays) on the third instance.  This causes the first two pie slices to combine in one big slice, and causes the pies colors to get all screwed up.  I thought (and actually still think) the problem is that my functions are asynchronous, but everything I've tried, such as using jquery when().then(), or embeding functions as callbacks hasn't worked.

example:

```
function1(param1, function(){ function2(); } );
```

Here are the main functions at play - the arrays that are at issue are slicesStart[] and slicesEnd[]

```
//draws the Pie Slice
function drawSlice1(startAngle, endAngle, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();  // starts arc
    ctx.arc(107, 107, 75, startAngle, endAngle); //positions arc on canvas with x,y values, followed by radius, start angle, and end angle
    ctx.lineWidth = 50; // line width
    ctx.strokeStyle = color; //line color
    ctx.stroke(); //fills the arc's width with said width/color
}



//draws the main pie
function drawPie(radius, color) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(107, 107, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineWidth = 50;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
}



//draws the base pie (the white border and shadow)
function drawBasePie(radius, color){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(107, 107, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineWidth = 54;
    ctx.shadowBlur=2; //Sets shadow length
    ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'; // Sets the shadow color
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
}



//draws each sliver of a pie slice one by one.  Combined with setInterval() this creates an animation
function drawPieSlice(pievalue, slicecolor, startAngle, numberSlice) {  

    if(typeof pievalue != 'undefined') {    

        if (counter == (pievalue + 1)) {

            startValue = currentEndAngle;

            counter++;


            sStart = startAngle;

            sEnd = currentEndAngle;

            //slicesStart[numberSlice] = startAngle;

            //slicesEnd[numberSlice] = currentEndAngle;

            //document.getElementById(numberSlice).innerHTML = "Slice" + numberSlice + " startangle=" + slicesStart[numberSlice] + " and endangle=" + slicesEnd[numberSlice];




        } else if (counter > (pievalue + 1)) {

            //do nothing, thus ending the setInterval() loop

        } else {

            var beginAngle = startAngle * Math.PI;
            var endAngle = (currentEndAngle) * Math.PI;

            currentEndAngle = currentEndAngle + 0.01;

            var counterClockwise = false;

            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

            //draw the base pie, which gives the white border with shadow effect (see bottom of script for function)
            drawBasePie(75, "white");

            //draw the main pie, which uses the "No Category" color as it's base (see bottom of script for function)
            drawPie(75, "#DDDDDD");

            for(var i=1; i<=8; i++){

                if(slicesStart[i] != 1000) {    

                    bangle = slicesStart[i] * Math.PI;

                    eangle = slicesEnd[i] * Math.PI;

                    zed = i - 1;

                    drawSlice1(bangle, eangle, colors[zed]);

                }

            }

            drawSlice1(beginAngle, endAngle, slicecolor);



        }

        counter++;

    }

}   



//function that causes each slice to animate
function sliceWrite(a,b){

    //check if slice value is zero
    if(pievalues[a] == 0) {
        //if 0 do nothing
    } else {
        //set counter to zero for each insance of the drawPieSlice() function
        counter = 0;

        //fire drawPieSlice function including the pievalue(how big it is), the color, and where it starts on the arc 
        pieslice[a] = setInterval(function() { drawPieSlice(pievalues[a], b, startValue, a); }, 15);

        //these are the start and end values of each slice of the pie.  At the end of drawPieSlice() the start and end values are entered into these two arrays.  The next time drawPieSlice() is run, it checks these arrays and if they hold values, draws the previous slice[s].
        slicesStart[a] = sStart;        
        slicesEnd[a] = sEnd;

        document.getElementById('1').innerHTML += "Slice" + a + " startangle = " + slicesStart[a] + " and endangle = " + slicesEnd[a] + " and color = " + colors[a] + "<br><br>";

    }   

}



function animatePie(){

    //the following acts as a for() statement, but with a delay before each instance is run (the delay amount for each instance is stored in the times[] array).
    var x = 1;

    function sliceOrder() {
       setTimeout(function () {
          sliceWrite(x,colors[x]);            
          x++;
          if (x <= 8) {
             sliceOrder();
          }                        
       }, times[x])
    }

    sliceOrder()

}

animatePie();
```

If anyone has potential solution, I would be most grateful.  Also, see the current code in action on JSFiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/lennox02/a3jZe/5/

Comment: i clicked on your fiddle and it didn't work the first time, i refreshed and now it's working but i can't get it to not work again, really weird

Comment: Same here. OP must have found the solution.

Comment: Hey Guys, no it's still not working - that's strange that it didn't work the first time.  The thing to remember, is that the piechart animates, it's just animating incorrectly.  If you see a piechart that has one big first slice (the first 8 slices should be 10% each), then the my problem still exists.  Also, you should notice that under the piechart it says the start and end angles for slices 1 and 2 are 0

Answer (score 0):

dont be upset, but there is nothing mysterious about it. it's simple very bad programming.

you use setInterval and setTimeout asynchron, the new setTimeout should be started when the setInterval (counter>20) finshes, if a new setTimeout starts before the setInterval finsihes then your global variables will show wrong values for action.

You also wrote:
you should notice that under the piechart it says the start and end angles for slices 1 and 2 are 0

thats also not mysterious because at the moment you are writing the values into the dom they are 0.

i think you should write the code again with more structure in thinking.

Comment: As I said in my original question, I'm aware the issue is that the functions are firing asynchronously, but what I've tried such as jquery's .when() function and embeding functions as a callback has not worked.  I'm not a javascript programmer, I specialize in php, so forgive me if my programming is "very bad" by your standards.  I'm not claiming to be particularly good, I'm simply asking for help in how I should write the code to make it synchronous.

Comment: write the code again simply animating one slice by interval and clear the interval and reset the width counter. if you have the function put up the fiddle. i looked through your fiddle but i didnt find a clearInterval or a reseting of your counter (slice width), and so on and so on.  if only something misses, i could help you in short definitions but here i would have torewrite the code completly, thats not mine thats your work-. if you dont want to rewrite all, perhaps some other guy will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctx=PieChart.getContext("2d");

//***********************************************************
//-------------------------------------- your drawing methods
//***********************************************************
//draws the Pie Slice
function drawSlice(startAngle, endAngle, color) 
    {
    ctx.beginPath();  // starts arc
    ctx.arc(107, 107, 75, startAngle, endAngle); //positions arc on canvas with x,y values, followed by radius, start angle, and end angle
    ctx.lineWidth = 50; // line width
    ctx.strokeStyle = color; //line color
    ctx.stroke(); //fills the arc's width with said width/color
    }

 //draws the main pie
function drawPie(radius, color) 
    {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(107, 107, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineWidth = 50;
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
    }

//draws the base pie (the white border and shadow)
function drawBasePie(radius, color)
    {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(107, 107, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.lineWidth = 54;
    ctx.shadowBlur=2; //Sets shadow length
    ctx.shadowColor = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)'; // Sets the shadow color
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.stroke();
    }

//***********************************************************
//-------------------------------------- your drawing methods -- END
//***********************************************************

//************************************************************
//-------------------------------------- Class slice Animation
//************************************************************

//-------- constructor
function sliceAnimation (startAngle, endAngle, color, time, frequency)
    {
    this.startAngle=startAngle;                            //-- start angle
    this.endAngle=endAngle;                                //-- end angle
    this.color=color;                                                                //-- color
    this.currentAngle=startAngle                           //-- current angle
    this.RFPS=(endAngle-startAngle)*1000/(frequency*time); //-- rad forward per step
    this.frequency=frequency                               //-- frequency
    this.timer=null;                                       //-- timer pointer
    this.callback=null;                                    //-- call back method
    this.callback_context=window;                                                    //-- the context of the call back action - where this should point to
    }

//-----------------------------------------------------
//-------- prototype
//-----------------------------------------------------
sliceAnimation.prototype.start=function ()
    {
    this.timer=setInterval (this.ACTION.bind(this),1/this.frequency*1000);    //-- setting the timer and binding slice Animation instance to the ACTION method, because the context of every setInterval or setTimeout call is window and not the instance of this class
    }

 sliceAnimation.prototype.ACTION=function ()
    {
    var currentAngle=this.currentAngle, endAngle=this.endAngle;               //-- quicker references
    var complete=false;
    currentAngle+=this.RFPS;                                                  //-- calculating the currentAngle
    if (currentAngle>endAngle)                                                //-- if endangle reached, clear the interval , set the currentAngle to the exact endAngle, and set complete to true
        {
        currentAngle=endAngle;
        clearInterval(this.timer);
        drawSlice (this.startAngle, currentAngle, this.color);
        complete=true;
        }
    drawSlice (this.startAngle, currentAngle, this.color);                                    //-- draws the slice
    this.currentAngle=currentAngle;                                           //-- sets the currentAngle in the instance
    if (complete && this.callback) this.callback.call (this.callback_context);//-- calls back if the endangle is reached under the callback context
    }
 //-----------------------------------------------------
 //-------- prototype -- END
 //-----------------------------------------------------
//************************************************************
//-------------------------------------- Class slice Animation
//************************************************************


//-- class pieSlice
function pieSlice (startAngle, endAngle, color, time)
    {
    this.startAngle=startAngle; 
    this.endAngle=endAngle;           //-- start angle
    this.color=color;                 //-- slice color
    this.time=time;                   //-- time it takes to animate in ms
    }

 //-- setting the 8 slices
var RF=Math.PI/4;                   //-- rad forward per slice
var CP=0;                           //-- currentPosition
var slices=new Array (
    new pieSlice (CP,CP+=RF, "green",      1000),   //-- startAngle, endAngle, color, time in ms
    new pieSlice (CP,CP+=RF, "blue",       1000),
    new pieSlice (CP,CP+=RF, "red",        1000),
    new pieSlice (CP,CP+=RF, "yellow",     1000),
    new pieSlice (CP,CP+=RF, "lightgreen", 1000),
    new pieSlice (CP,CP+=RF, "purple",     1000),
    new pieSlice (CP,CP+=RF, "brown",      1000),
    new pieSlice (CP,CP+=RF, "grey",       1000));


 function pieAnimation (frequency, delay, slices)
     {
     this.slices=slices;
     this.slicesL=slices.length;
     this.sliceCounter=0;
     this.frequency=frequency;
     this.delay=delay;
     }

 pieAnimation.prototype.start=function ()
    {
    ctx.clearRect (0,0,215,215);        //-- clears the area
    drawBasePie (75,"lightgrey");   //-- draws your backgrounds
    drawPie (75, "#DDDDDD");
    this.ACTION (); 
    }

 pieAnimation.prototype.ACTION=function ()
     {
     var slice, animation;

   if (this.sliceCounter<this.slicesL)   //--- going through all slices
        {
          slice=slices[this.sliceCounter];
          animation=new sliceAnimation (slice.startAngle, slice.endAngle, slice.color, slice.time, this.frequency);  // setting a new slice Animation
          animation.callback=this.ACTION;                                                                            // setting the callback of the sliceAnimation which is this function (instance.ACTION)
          animation.callback_context=this;                                                                           // setting the context to the instance of pieAnimation
          this.sliceCounter++;                                                                                       // increase the sliceCounter
          setTimeout (animation.start.bind (animation), this.delay);                                                 // starts the sliceAnimation
          }
    }

 var animation=new pieAnimation (25,20, slices);                                                                //instance of pieAnimation
 animation.start ();                                                                                            //starts the animation
```